# Teechart Custom Lengend tool

Tags: activex, teechart

I want to show a table for  Box Plot containing Values such as mean Median , S.D , Range etc.
The Data Table tool shows only X, X2 data doesn't allow for customization data.I am trying too use Custom Legend Tool using which we can create Table specifying Grid Row and Column. Can anyone let me know how we can enter data into the table.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you are using VC++. The CustomLegend tool is a quite new tool and I'm afraid there are some features missing in it for VC++.
I've added it to the wish list to be implemented in future releases ([TA05015410/B395](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=395)).

In the meanwhile, note TeeChart ActiveX supports custom drawing so you can manually draw your table if the other tools in the component don't allow you to draw what you exactly want to.

Custom drawing techniques basically consist on a set of methods and properties (set the Canvas Pen, Brush and Font, and draw lines, shapes or texts) to draw directly onto the canvas. These methods are commonly called at the OnAfterDraw event so the custom drawing can be redone after each repaint.

You can find examples written in VC++ under the `\Examples\Visual C++\Version 6\` folder in your TeeChart ActiveX installation. Concretely, you can see a simple example of how to use custom drawing techniques in the `Dragging Points` project. In the DraggingDlg.cpp file you can see how some custom drawing techniques are used in the OnAfterDraw method:

```
void CDraggingDlg::OnAfterDrawTChart() 
{
    // Draw a white circle around the clicked pyramid...
    if (-1 != m_ClickedBar)
    {
        CCanvas aCanvas = m_ctrlChart.GetCanvas();
        CPen1 aPen = aCanvas.GetPen();
        aPen.SetColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
        aPen.SetWidth(1);
        aPen.SetStyle(psDot);
        aCanvas.GetBrush().SetStyle(bsClear);
        int x = m_ctrlChart.Series(0).CalcXPos(m_ClickedBar);
        int y = m_ctrlChart.Series(0).CalcYPos(m_ClickedBar);
        aCanvas.Ellipse(x, y, x + 40, y + 40);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you share with me a custom drawing code. So that I can implement it.

Comment: Till when can we expect TA05015410 Releases

Comment: I've incremented the ticket priority but I'm afraid I can't tell you when it will be implemented.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Feel free to add your mail to the CC list on the ticket to be automatically notified when an update arrives: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=395